# Como puedo modificar un elemento de una listbox Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Como puedo modificar un elemento de una listbox sin necesidad de crear un boton aparte, es decir que haga doble click sobre un elemento y se transforme en un Entry y cuando pulse enter se cambie el valor del elemento seleccionado al que hay en el entry

```
from tkinter import *
ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x600")
Lista = Listbox(ventana,width=50,height=3)
Lista.place(x=50,y=50)
Lista.insert(0,"Como puedo modificar")
Lista.insert(1,"un elemento")
Lista.insert(2,"de esta lista?")
ventana.mainloop() sin necesidad de crear un boton aparte, es decir que haga doble click sobre un elemento y se transforme en un Entry y cuando pulse enter se cambie el valor del elemento seleccionado

from tkinter import *
ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x600")
Lista = Listbox(ventana,width=50,height=3)
Lista.place(x=50,y=50)
Lista.insert(0,"Como puedo modificar")
Lista.insert(1,"un elemento")
Lista.insert(2,"de esta lista?")
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por desgracia el widget `ListBox` solo puede contener texto, no otros widgets como items. Lo que podrías hacer es crear una clase propia y hacer uso de `place` para posicionar un `Entry` en la misma posición del item seleccionado.

La clave está en conseguir la posición y tamaño del item seleccionado, lo cual puedes conseguir en principio con `ListBox.winfo_width()`, `ListBox.x()`, `ListBox.y()` y `ListBox.bbox()`.

Algo básico podría ser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk



class EditableListBox(tk.Listbox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self._parent = parent
        self._entry = tk.Entry(self._parent)
        self.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self._on_double_button_1)
        self._entry.bind('<Return>', self._on_entry_enter)
        self._index = None

    def _on_entry_enter(self, _):
        new_value = self._entry.get()
        self._entry.place_forget()
        self.config(state="normal")
        self.delete(self._index)
        self.insert(self._index, new_value)

    def _on_double_button_1(self, _):
        idx = self.curselection()
        if idx:
            self.config(state="disabled")
            self._index = idx[0]
            value = self.get(self.curselection())
            _, yoffset, _, height = self.bbox(self.curselection())

            width = self.winfo_width()
            x = self.winfo_x()
            y = self.winfo_y() + yoffset
            self._entry.place(x=x, y=y, width=width, height=height)
            self._entry.focus_set()
            self._entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self._entry.insert(0, value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('500x300')
    var = tk.StringVar()
    var.set(tuple(range(100)))
    lb = EditableListBox(window, listvariable=var)
    lb.place(x=50,y=50)
    window.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Edición**

El método `ListBox.bbox()` para un item dado retorna una tupla de la forma:

```
(desplazamiento_en_x, desplazamiento_en_y, ancho, alto)
```

Las dos primeras variables indican la posición relativa del item con respecto a la propia `ListBox`, de forma que el primer item tendria `0` como coordenada <kbd>y</kbd>. Por tanto, para posicionar correctamente el `Entry` encima del item seleccionado es necesario añadir a las coordenadas anteriores las coordenadas de la propia `ListBox` con respecto a su contenedor:

```
y = self.winfo_y() + yoffset
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la ayuda, aun tengo un pequeño problema ricien inicio en este mundillo de la programación y aun no se muy bien como funcionan las clases y eso por lo que traspase el código a lo "cavernicola" para entender bien lo que estoy haciendo y como funciona,  pero tengo el siguiente problema: cuando hago doble click sobre un elemento el entry aparece en otras coordenadas ¿como lo podría solucionar? El código: https://pastebin.com/QB0BczJe Gracias por tu ayuda y tiempo <3

Comment: Hola Franco, error mio, se me pasó añadir la posición del propio ListBox a la de su item. He editado la respuesta añadido una explicación. Para tu ejemplo, en principio bastaría con  añadir la línea `y += lb.winfo_y()`. No se si se me habrá escapado algo más, cualquier cosa comenta. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tengo otra duda por que cuando intento seleccionar dentro del Entry, ya sea con control + a o simplemente seleccionando con el mouse se de-selecciona el elemento que quería modificar al principio y al apretar enter salta un error, con el ejemplo que me pasaste esto no pasa pero en mi código "cavernicola" si. La única solución que encontré es desactivando la combinación del teclas ctrl + a y el seleccionado con el mouse, pero me quedo medio inconforme, no habría alguna forma de solucionarlo?, mi código: https://pastebin.com/FYDN3eyc

Comment: @Franco no puedo probar nada ahora, pero sospecho lo que pasa. Deberías obtener el índice del elemento seleccionado en el listbox (`select = lb.curselection()`) en la callaback `doubleClick`, no en `enter_`. Usa una variable global para almacenar el índice y poder usarlo en `enter_` luego. El problema es que al seleccionar en el Entry pierdes la selección del ListBox y por tanto el índice retornado es "", causando que `lb.delete(select)`  falle.

Comment: Hola soy yo de nuevo jajaja,me podrías ayudar a hacer las listbox pero en clases, como lo que me pasaste pero algo mas sencillo por que apenas entiendo la mitad del código y no quiero simplemente copiar y pegar por que realmente eso no me sirve para aprender. Intente por algunos días hacerlo por mi cuenta pero no me queda la parte de modificar la listbox me salta error cuando pongo el parametro `tk.Listbox` en la clase pero necesito que este para individualizar las listbox mi codigo: https://pastebin.com/JC988sZQ ,de verdad gracias por toda tu ayuda.

Comment: Hola Franco, si no entiendes cualquier cosa de mi código puedes preguntar lo que quieras, podemos lanzar una sala de chat incluso para aclarar cualquier duda que tengas sobre la respuesta, por mi no hay problema alguno. En cuanto a tu nuevo código puedes publicar una nueva pregunta dado que es una nueva duda. Ahí será más fácil contestar que por comentarios.

Comment: Ya hice una nueva publicación. No se como abrir una sala de chat